# Given a number and a length, prepend (length - number.count) 0s to that int in a performant manner in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string

I am trying to create a helper function that prepends x amounts of zeroes to the integer where x is the difference between a given length and the number of characters in that int.

For example:

```
     // data = 9573132375
     // length = 15
     // should return (15 - 10) 000009573132375
     public string ModulateData(long data, int length)
     {
        if (data.ToString().Length <= length)
        {
            int noToPrepend = length - data.ToString().Length;
            string leadingzeros = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < noToPrepend; i++)
            {
                leadingzeros += "0";
            }

            return leadingzeros + data.ToString();
        } 
        return "";
     }
```

I can only think of converting the data variable to a string, prepending 0s, and converting the string back to an integer later. However, I am concerned about the performance of this approach, as this method will be part of my core design, it needs to be as performant as possible. Is there a faster way this can be done? Are there any performance penalties with my current code?

EDIT
I am communicating the data variable as request data to a machine that accepts bytes, so I will be using this function as follows -

```
string requestdata = "";
requestdata += ModulateData(x,20);
requestdata += ModulateData(y,5);
requestdata += ModulateData(z,10); // Could be about 20 or so lines like this.
```

After that I will convert requestdata to a byte array in Hex Format. I already have working code for that.

Comment: Do you know about [string.PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft) ?

Comment: Indeed, `data.ToString().PadLeft(length)` would be my suggested starting point. (And yes, it's expensive to perform repeated concatenation left this, *and* you're converting `data` to a string twice.)

Comment: Thank you, I just read up on the documentation and I believe I could refactor my above function. However, I am keen on hearing opinions on performance, or other methods that may be better.

Comment: Just `return data.ToString($"d{length}");`

Comment: "prepending 0s, and converting the string back to an integer later" Why are you converting the string back to an integer? That will remove the leading 0s (because numbers don't have leading 0s)...

Comment: Indeed. 1 = 01 = 001 = 0001, etc. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need the leading zeros?

Comment: As far as performance goes, the best way of determining performance is to test it with the code you're using, in the situation you're using it, using benchmarking software.

Comment: Whether to use `PadLeft()` or to use `ToString($"d{length}")` depends on if you want to support negative numbers, and in that case whether you want the "-" sign to replace one of the leading zeros or not. (Use `PadLeft()` if you do want to replace a zero, or `ToString($"d{length}")` if you don't.

Comment: I dont need to support negative numbers, There shouldnt be any '-' in the final string.

Comment: @HereticMonkey maybe I am trying to optimize too early, I have created a console application where I whack this function in a for loop with the logic I just edited the question with. I will use ToString($"d{length}" and PadLeft() to compare results.

Comment: If `data` is longer than the specified `length`, you are ignoring that data and returning an empty string (length = 0) - are you sure that's what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shorter version:

```cs
public static string ModulateData(long data, int length) =>
            (data.ToString().Length <= length)
                ? $"{new string('0', length - data.ToString().Length)}{data}"
                : string.Empty;
```

And more **debuggable** version, if you want:

```cs
public static string ModulateData(long data, int length)
{
    var dataAsText = data.ToString();

    if (dataAsText.Length <= length)
    {
        int noToPrepend = length - dataAsText.Length;
        var leadingZeros = new string('0', noToPrepend);

        return $"{leadingZeros}{dataAsText}";
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

---

And a usage:

```cs
// to make this more optimal you can calculate the StringBuilder initial capacity here, 
// by taking into account possible characters length output
var requestData = new StringBuilder(); 

requestData.Append(ModulateData(x, 20));
requestData.Append(ModulateData(y, 5));
requestData.Append(ModulateData(z, 10));
```